Creating a UI with using Win Ui in python
i am trying to create a desktop app using python firstly i create a folder and next open in vs code and create files like winui.py and page.xaml  and then run this code and give me some related to runtime and msix than download runtime 1.5 and msix and try to run this code but it again give me same error.
please help me for creating a ui using python.

It is hard to help you. Please provide your code and the error message as text

@oskar i don't  know ho can i add the code can you help me ,please

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have resolved the issue.
